# plot from file in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

robot4_motors.txt

```
M 204 20795 20795 3000 0 16067 16066 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 524 20795 20794 3000 0 16067 16066 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 735 20795 20795 3000 0 16067 16066 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 995 20795 20795 3000 0 16067 16067 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 995 20795 20795 3000 0 16067 16067 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 1233 20795 20795 3000 0 16067 16067 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 1499 20795 20795 3000 0 16067 16067 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 1763 20795 20795 3000 0 16067 16067 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
```

This is a data file. I want to take out 3rd column and 7th column from the file and plot them as well. I write down the code in matlab.

Code

```
f = fopen('robot4_motors.txt');
plot(f(:, 3), f(:, 7))
```

But the code did not work .

Throws error ***Index in position 2 exceeds array*** ***bounds (must not exceed 1).***

***Error in trick1 (line 21)
plot(f(:, 3), f(:, 7))***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fopen` returns a numeric id which refers to the opened file, it's not a matrix. You need to parse the file to extract the data.

One way to parse the file is to use [`dlmread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) since this is a space delimited file.

```
% Read data into M starting at row 0, column 1.
M = dlmread('robot4_motors.txt', ' ', 0, 1);
```

After this, `M` will contain all the entries from the file except the first column (which aren't numeric).

```
>> M
M = 
     204       20795       20795        3000           0       16067       16066        3000           0           0           0        6000           0
     524       20795       20794        3000           0       16067       16066        3000           0           0           0        6000           0
     735       20795       20795        3000           0       16067       16066        3000           0           0           0        6000           0
     995       20795       20795        3000           0       16067       16067        3000           0           0           0        6000           0
     995       20795       20795        3000           0       16067       16067        3000           0           0           0        6000           0
    1233       20795       20795        3000           0       16067       16067        3000           0           0           0        6000           0
    1499       20795       20795        3000           0       16067       16067        3000           0           0           0        6000           0
    1763       20795       20795        3000           0       16067       16067        3000           0           0           0        6000           0
```